# Implement a low-pass single pole with 20 Hz cutoff frequency

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter

i'm trying to implement a low-pass this way, as in the `Digital signal processing guide` book, but my `alfa = 2.660393305517957e-55` which is obviously wrong. Here's the code:

```
x = exp(-2*pi*20);

a0 = 1 - x;
b1 = x;

eda2(1) = eda_raw2(1);

for n = 2:length(eda_raw2)
    eda2(n) = a0*eda_raw2(n) + b1.*eda2(n - 1);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you are computing the pole (`x`) of the discrete-time filter. You are not considering the sampling frequency! The computation should be `x = exp(-2*pi*20/fm);`, where `fm` is the sampling frequency in Hz.

Comment: even using my sampling frequency 100 Hz the value is still 0.28 so there's no filtering at all

Comment: x = exp(-2*pi*20/100) = 0.2846;

Comment: Of course there is filtering. Try your code on `eda_raw2 = [1 zeros(1,9) ];` and see how `eda2` slowly decays

Comment: would my window size matter too? it's 30 seconds

Comment: The window size of what?

Comment: the size of signal. 30 seconds

Comment: The only effect of that is: the filter has a transient of the order of 1/20 s. So in the first few tenths of a second your filtered signal may show that transient effect.

Answer (score 0):

Check the online mathworks page : [Low Pass Filter Design](http://www.mathworks.in/help/dsp/ref/fdesign.lowpass.html)

Comment: I understand that, but I'm trying to understand what's wrong in this implementation.It's not about Matlab.